# Determining overlap and subsets of multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, venn-diagram

I have six different sets of data, each of which are data frames that are about 10,000 rows or larger and have two columns. One column contains peak names, such as "peak_1", the other the frequency. Some of these data frames contain the same peaks, and some dont. My goal is to find out which peaks are in which overlapping subsets of these six dataframes (there are 63 different possible combinations with 6 datasets). I found packages that could find out venn diagram subsets (which is what i am looking for), but not for 6 datasets, and i have tried using `%in%` and `which`, but with the size of my datasets i was hitting roadblocks that i couldnt figure out. I tried to determine it by hand by merging the files into all possible combinations then calculating the size of each subset by hand from the size of the files, but i seem to have take missteps there and i need to know what is contained in each subset, and not just the size.

Example:

```
dataA             dataB            dataC
V1      V2        V1       V2      V1       V2
peak1   3         peak2    1       peak1    1
peak2   1         peak3    2       peak4    3
peak5   2         peak4    1       peak6    1
peak8   1         peak8    2       peak8    4
peak9   2
```

This is the result i am hoping to achieve, where dataX is a different dataframe (or something similar... i need to at least have new tables i can save as files)

```
dataA       dataB       dataC      dataAB      dataAC      dataBC      dataABC   
V1    V2    V1    V2    V1    V2   V1     V2   V1     V2   V1    V2    V1    V2
peak5 2     peak3 2     peak6 1    peak2  2    peak1  4    peak4 4     peak8 7
peak9 2
```

I know this was long-winded, but any suggestions will be welcomed, as it seems like something that should be much more straight-forward than i am making it!

Comment: My initial gut reaction is to create a big dataframe using `dplyr::bind_rows(..., .id="source")` first. Then you could generate various crosstabulations to get insights into source and occurrence of the different peaks. With such a "master-dataframe" you could create an additional indicator for `either data source A or data source B`, and use that in further processing.

Comment: One problem is of course that your desired output is a bit unclear, actually. For instance, in your `dataA` column, what happened to all the other values not listed any more? What caused them to be dropped?

Comment: Looks like an unwise direction. Better would be to rbind them and work with the long form.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're looking for the maximum for `V2` for each level of `V1`, and to know what data.frame it came from, you can use the following:

```
library(dplyr)

# add a row to each with its name so there's a record after the join
dataA$df <- 'dataA'
dataB$df <- 'dataB'
dataC$df <- 'dataC'

# use dplyr version of rbind (use regular, if you prefer)
alldata <- bind_rows(dataA, dataB, dataC)

# dplyr chain that groups by V1 (peak), then chops to rows where V2 is equal 
# to its max for each group, then arrange by peak so it's pretty
alldata %>% group_by(V1) %>% filter(V2 == max(V2)) %>% arrange(V1)
```

which returns

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: V1 [8]

     V1    V2    df
  (chr) (int) (chr)
1 peak1     3 dataA
2 peak2     1 dataA
3 peak2     1 dataB
4 peak3     2 dataB
5 peak4     3 dataC
6 peak5     2 dataA
7 peak6     1 dataC
8 peak8     4 dataC
9 peak9     2 dataA
```

Note that there's two maximums for `peak2` at the moment, which both get selected with this approach.

---

Data:

```
dataA <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:5, .Label = c("peak1", "peak2", 
"peak5", "peak8", "peak9"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

dataB <- structure(list(V1 = structure(2:5, .Label = c("", "peak2", "peak3", 
"peak4", "peak8"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))

dataC <- structure(list(V1 = structure(2:5, .Label = c("", "peak1", "peak4", 
"peak6", "peak8"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 4L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using alistaire's data:

```
dl <- do.call(rbind, list(dataA,dataB,dataC))
# make a source indicator
unlist(mapply(rep, 1:3, sapply(list(dataA,dataB,dataC), NROW) ) )
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
dl$source= unlist(mapply(rep, 1:3, sapply(list(dataA,dataB,dataC), NROW) ) )
```

Now can identify which V1's have a particular pattern with:

```
> table(dl$V1, dl$source)

        1 2 3
  peak1 1 0 1
  peak2 1 1 0
  peak5 1 0 0
  peak8 1 1 1
  peak9 1 0 0
        0 0 0
  peak3 0 1 0
  peak4 0 1 1
  peak6 0 0 1
```

So can see that 'peak8' is in all three.